# How to submit toggled Data to change the status of my boolean in my mysql via Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, eloquent

I would like to change the status of my boolean in my msql5.7 when I click a button in my view.

I want that when I click on my button, the value of my boolean is switched( toggled between 0 and 1)

Here is my ajax code (my Dashboard.blade.php)

```
function reply_click(clicked_id){
    $(function() {
        $('#openButton').on('click', function(data) {
            $.get("test.php", {clicked_id);
        });
    });
}
```

my DashboardController.php

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{   
    public function index() {  
        return view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

my migration file

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('chaves',function (Blueprint $table){
        $table -> increments('id');
        $table -> string('nome');
        $table -> boolean('alugado');
        $table -> timestamps();
    });
}
```

my route

```
Route::get("dashboard", "DashboardController@index")->name("dashboard")->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: do you mean that if you hit the button.. the boolean value in your table of DB will be change? or what?

Comment: @JamesRiady, exactly !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery

```
function reply_click(clicked_id){
        $(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
               headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
               }
            });
            $('#openButton').on('click', function(data) {
                $.ajax({
                  type: "PATCH",
                  url: "/dashboard"
                })
                .done(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .fail(function(data){
                    console.log('Error:', data);
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Controller

```
use App\Chave; //use this if you have model
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; //use this if you don't have model
class DashboardController extends Controller
{   
    public function index() { 
        $dashboard = Chave::first(); //use this if you have model
        $dashboard = DB::table('chaves')->first();
        $dashboard->alugado = 1;
        $dashboard->save();
        return view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Router

```
Route::patch("dashboard", "DashboardController@index")->name("dashboard")->middleware('auth');
```

I think that you have to use method Patch and not using Get in your router.. because in this case, you are trying to do update but not update all..

**Put method is used to update partial resource**

Comment: I received a synfony error: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException, I believe it is related to the patch method

Comment: I have added ajaxsetup in my code.. lets try it again

Comment: let try to do `return response()->json($dashboard);` below of `$dashboard = Dashboard::first();` and see what it returns

Comment: how about change the method into get?

Comment: OK, I changed the `method type: "PATCH"` to `type: "GET"`, and route to `Route :: get`, so I got another error in my DashboardController.php -> 'Class' App \ Http \ Controllers \ Dashboard' not found "

Comment: in this line -> `$dashboard = Dashboard::first();`

Comment: why do you change the model name into `Dashboard`.. look at my answer.. I change it into `Chave`.. when you make a migration, you should make a model too.. the model name has same with migration name.. when you migration name is `chaves`, your model name should be `Chave`

Comment: I do not have a model, I just created the migration file. `import App\Chave;` is returning an error from my controller -> {
 "resource": "/app/Http/Controllers/DashboardController.php", -> `syntax error, unexpected 'App' (T_STRING),`

Comment: maybe u should start from beginning.. delete your model that you create before and delete the migration.. then do this in your command line `php artisan make: model Chave`. This will create a model and a migration,, then input your field in migration file, and migrate it.. and try to run your code again

Comment: If you don't want to use model.. see my code again.. I will add my code

Comment: I created a blank template as you advised me, and it worked, I was able to change the value of the first field in my table, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on('click', '.update', function() {
            var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
              function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{!! url('your_url' ) !!}" + "/" +id,
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {id: id, "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", _method: 'PATCH'},
                        success: function (data) {

                        }
                    });

                },
                function () {
                    return false;
                });
        });
```

Comment: I believe that the solution is at the controller level.